# Append excel files with different columns in python

Tags: python, excel, append

I have multiple excel files with different column names. I want to append content of one excel file to another. I don't want to merge. If there are 10 rows in first excel file and 12 rows in second file I want the second file's 12 rows to be appended from row 11 of first file.This is what I have tried ,but this merges columns and column names  of second file are moved to row 1 of first file

```
tickers = ['2crsi','abeo']
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in tickers:
    df2 = pd.read_excel(f"./balance/pea/{ticker}.xls") 
    df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2])


    df2 = pd.read_excel(f"./keyratio/pea/{ticker}.xls") 
    df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
    

    df2 = pd.read_excel(f"./history/pea/{ticker}.xls") 
    df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2])


    df2 = pd.read_excel(f"./cashflow/pea/{ticker}.xls") 
    df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2])

df1.to_excel(f'{ticker}.xls')
```

Comment: have you looked at the ```append()``` method, that would meet your requirement. see details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#concatenating-using-append)

Comment: when the column names are different, then the append and concat methods are going to create separate columns for that, it will not merge.